# Java 11 module-info and annotation processors

Tags: java, annotation-processing, module-info

How can we provide an annotation processor with a Java 11 module?

To register the annotation provider we need the following module-info entry:

```
import javax.annotation.processing.Processor;
import com.mycompany.mylib.impl.MyAnnotationProcessor;

module com.mycompany.mylib {

    provides Processor with MyAnnotationProcessor;

}
```

Now, unfortunately, this is not enough since the packages `javax.annotation.processing`, `javax.lang.model.*` and `javax.tools` are not in the `java.base` module but in the `java.compiler` module.

With Java SE 8 everything was just available in the JRE, but with Java 11 we get the option to use only a subset. With `jlink` we then can create smaller runtime images.

Now, of course, I could just add the following to the module-info:

```
requires java.compiler;
```

But this would cause `java.compiler` to be part of the custom runtime image as well.

But annotation processing is something special: it is code run at compile time, not at runtime. Thus it should not be part of the runtime image. It should only be a compile-time requirement/ dependency.

Is there a way to solve this with the Java 11 module system?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you should write

> requires static java.compiler;

It's stated in the JLS 7.7.1 that

> The requires keyword may be followed by the modifier `static`. This specifies that the dependence, while mandatory at compile time, is optional at run time.